# How to fix this 'Prototype Segue' related with my NSCollectionView (Xcode 7.0 beta)

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, segue, nscollectionview

So I've always wanted to code a program for OSX with Swift that needs a Collection View. As it is for OSX, it doesn't use a UICollectionView but a NSCollectionView (by the way, if you know any tutorial to use these with Swift it'll be much appreciated !).

The thing is : I put a 'Collection View' in my storyboard, make it my initial controller, and as the view was created it also created a NSCollectionViewItem on the storyboard. In Xcode 6 the prototype item was absolutely not related to any other element of the storyboard, but now in Xcode 7 it is created with a 'Prototype Segue'.

Problem : When I compile, I've got this error :

```
Unknown segue relationship : Prototype
```

Anyone has an idea on how to fix it ?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my english --'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have to specify connection manually.

1. Add "collectionViewItem" Storyboard ID to your collection view item.

[image: screenshot]

2. Add the following code to viewDidLoad method of your Collection View's controller (Swift example):

   ```
   self.collectionView.itemPrototype = self.storyboard!.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("collectionViewItem") as! NSCollectionViewItem
   ```

Comment: as of Xcode 7 beta 6 that is no longer possible. Xcode will show the following error if you set the itemPrototype: Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): Use -registerNib:forItemWithIdentifier: and -registerClass:forItemWithIdentifier: with new CollectionViews

Comment: As @gbdavid said, I really don't understand why they turned off this option, since they added storyboards... And now work with nibs. Some edits to the answer would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

As of XCode 7.2, nd OSX 10.11 the issue is still there, the only way around this is by creating a nib based collection view cell and calling the method - (void)registerNib:(nullable NSNib *)nib forItemWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier on the collection view.

Comment: This is very bad. But the worst is that the 'registerNib' function is available only since OS X 10.11. So am I really not able to create collection view as of now ? Can't believe that.

Comment: @Lubos the state of the Cocoa API for OS X is absolutely horrible. Having started developing in Objective-C for iOS, I can see why people say they hate Cocoa. The entire iOS API seems to be refined 100 times over compared to the mess that is the OS X counterpart. Maybe it's just me, being used to iOS' API, but the OS X one seems so polluted with things that should have been long since deprecated, weird naming conventions NSZeroSize (not NSSizeZero) and its Rect and Point counterparts, to draw attention to the tip of the iceberg.